# Asignar valor a un input file

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

Tengo un campo de tipo `input file` en un formulario. Una vez relleno el formulario le doy a un botón *Insertar* que inserta los valores y el nombre del archivo en una base de datos.

Estos registros ya almacenados me los muestra en una tabla, el problema es que cuando le doy en consultar me rellena las casillas del formulario bien, excepto el `input file`, y no se si es posible mostrar el nombre del archivo ya guardado en un `input file` al momento de una consulta. `Código:`

```
$("#id_evidencias").val(td[0].innerText);
$("#idactividad_L").val(td[1].innerText);
$("#fecha_evidencia").val(td[2].innerText);
$("#nombre_evidencia").val(td[3].innerText);

document.getElementsById('file').value = td[4].innerText;
```

`HTML:`

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="uploaded_file">Seleccionar Archivo *</label>
    <input type="file" name="uploaded_file" id="uploaded_file">
    <p class="help-block">Tamaño máximo 3MG.</p>
<div class="box-footer">
```

Comment: Como tienes el `html` del input file ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Te informo que por motivos de seguridad no puedes asignar el valor a un `input` de tipo `file` por medio de código, además de que el valor de esta clase de `input` hace referencia a una ruta física local de un archivo no únicamente a su nombre.

Lo que te recomendaría para mostrar tu archivo es añadir una etiqueta `img`, incluir dentro del atributo `src` la ruta del archivo y concatenar el nombre que te devuelve la consulta a la **DB**.

```
<img src="" alt="Mi imagen" id="miImagen">

$("#miImagen").attr('src', 'miruta/' + td[4].innerText)
```

Después de esto puedes agregar un botón que permita al usuario subir una nueva imagen para reemplazar la anterior si así lo deseas.